# Is there a format string that can be passed to the VB6 Format function that will simply group digits?

Tags: vb6, string-formatting

Is there a format string (?) I can pass to the VB6 Format function that will perform digit grouping?  I want to replace the question mark in this statement...

```
Debug.Print Format(123456789, "?")
```

...with a string that will generate the following output:

```
123,456,789
```

The predefined format string "Standard" comes close, but it tacks a decimal point and two 0's on the end:

```
? Format(123456789, "Standard")
123,456,789.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was typing the question I took another glance at the documentation and spotted the answer, but I went ahead and posted it anyway.  Here it is:

```
Debug.Print Format(123456789, "#,##0")
```

Comment: Ask a question, and then answer it yourself? Is this a sneaky way to get more rep points? Must try it myself :)

Comment: Joacim is inccorrect. The comma in the format string is replaced with the appropriate digit grouping symbol. I have just set my PC to Spanish regional settings and ?format$(123456789, "#,##0") gives the following: 123.456.789

Comment: @MarkJ: Cool.  Thanks for the verification.  I should have done that myself (I just did).